# How to declare New or Hot tag in E-Commerce product and after 15 days these tags will remove automatically

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, e-commerce

I am learning Django and creating an e-commerce site. I want to add a tag as ** new ** to my newly arrived products. This tag will be removed automatically after 5/7/15 or 30 days.
Also if any product has a big amount of discounts such as 30%, 40%, or more, these products will have a **HOT** tag automatically. The tag will be automatically removed when the offer expires.

Please let me know, how can I do these.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share some code regarding tag and product model?

Answer (score 0):

`django` by itself doesn't change the fields as you desire.

I think you should define `task`, which is responsible for checking the `tag` field of the model (that is boolean), and change it to False if it's for more than 30 days.

At first, you need to add `tag` and `hot` to your product model.

Then for creating a periodic task, you can use `celery`. It helps you to create a periodic task and easy to work with.

I think a daily task is suitable for your goal.

Then you can define another task for checking the `hot` field too.
maybe the following instruction will help you:

https://medium.com/@ksarthak4ever/django-handling-periodic-tasks-with-celery-daaa2a146f14

Comment: You said, "change it to False if it's for more than 30 days." I thought about this way but I'm looking for an automatic way. Anyway, Thanks a lot for your response.